# Trying to use grep to find something, then output a different part of the line

Tags: linux, search, grep, output

Say for instance I'm searching a line that is like this:

Color asdf

and I use grep to find that line, like     grep asdf file.txt
How would I then display Color? Learning linux is hard.

Comment: Using sed would be easier.

Comment: Hmm I'm not too familiar with sed. Give me a second, and I'll try it out and see what happens. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `sed`:

```sh
sed -n 's/[[:space:]][[:space:]]*asdf$//p' file.txt
```

Details:

- The `-n` option tells `sed` not to print the pattern space automatically. Basically, it doesn't output anything unless you tell it to.
- The `s` command of `sed` replaces text. Here, if a line ends with `asdf`, preceded by at least one whitespace character, we replace all of that with nothing and then print the line (notice the `p` flag at the end of the `s` command). The printing is only done if something was actually replaced. More information about the `s` command can be found e. g. in the [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html).

**Edit** for clarity: When using single quotes, parameter expansion does not work and thus, variables won't be replaced. To use variables, use double quotes:

```sh
search=asdf
sed -n "s/[[:space:]][[:space:]]*${search}\$//p" file.txt
```

Comment: Additionally, if I wanted to turn that into a basic shell script, where I specified the text instead of "asdf", what would I use? I tried putting in $1 instead of asdf, but that didn't work.

Comment: Thanks again. You're the greatest. I would up-vote you if I had more reputation.

Answer (score 1):

With the command line tool `sed` you can replace stings by using regular expressions:

```
echo "Color asdf" | sed 's/\([^ ]*\).*/\1/'
```

This part: `\([^ ]*\).*` is a regular expresion. The first part of the regex: `[^ ]*`, matches any character except a space as many times as possible and what's between the `\(` and `\)` is being captured in the variable `\1`. Then you also match the remaining part of the string with `.*` and replace all of that with only the first word which was captured by `\([^ ]*\)` by using `\1` in the replace part of the `sed` command.

Here some more info about sed:
http://linux.about.com/od/commands/a/Example-Uses-Of-Sed-Cmdsedxa.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you'd really like to use `grep` here, you could pipe the output from `grep` into `cut`:

```
grep -h asdf *.txt | cut -s -d  -f 1
```

Note that there have to be two spaces after the `-d` option to `cut` - the first tells `cut` to use a blank as the field delimiter (I'm assuming your fields are blank-delimited rather than tab-delimited), while the second separates the `-d` option from the following option (`-f`).

But, yeah, `sed` or `awk` are probably your friends here... :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can color pattern in the line using grep

```
grep --colour -o 'asdf' file.txt
```

edit: the -o option will print only the patterns